# Best practices for avoiding downtime when making changes to the API?

Tags: reactjs, devops, production-environment, vercel, staging

I am making a React-Django application which I have deployed using Vercel.

**My concern is that sometimes I will need to make changes to the API and I am not sure how to handle that without causing downtime in production.**

Say for example that I change an endpoint's payload (for example, I might change the variable names or its structure). Say I reflect those changes in the frontend, making sure that the frontend can accept the new payload.

Now, if I push the new API to live and the front-end has not been pushed to live yet, the (old) front-end will make get a payload it won't be able to work with and thus the app will crash. If on the other hand I push the new front-end to live but the new API is not live yet, the (new) front-end will get the old payload's structure which it's no longer able to work with. The app will crash in this case too.

**How can I ensure that when I make changes to the API and to the frontend I can do so whilst also avoiding any downtime? What are the best practices to do this?**

(As a reminder, the app has a React frontend and a Django backend and is deployed through Vercel)

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a project I worked on before I added a notification queue broadcasting a notification to logged in users saying that we're having maintenance and I block any request and displaying a toast and I block the login for some minutes synchronizing with my team to build and post the front updates.

I used react as front Symfony php as API and I used Mercury as Messaging queue
in your case you can use sockets.

Or if you're sure that your users won't use your app late at night synchronize with your team to make updates late at night but it's risky if someone use it so that's why I notify my users for some minutes

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While I appreciate that sending users notifications to notify them that the platform will be down is one way of dealing with the problem, I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require contacting the users.